# Android Memory Leak? Bitmap exceeds VM budget error with Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, bitmap, out-of-memory

My Application contains several fragments as I am showing them in Two Tabs. Few Fragments were categorized into first Tab and few are into another Category which are shown is second tab. And it also have many images which will be fetched from the web. I am using lazy loading of images concept with no WeakReference or SoftReference to Bitmaps. Application works very much fine with no issues. But if I operate for long time then it crashes. I traced the heap update and found the below.

When I visit new Fragments, then heap size is increasing and when remove them from stack then heap size is not decreasing.If I visit old fragments then there is no huge amount increase in heap memory but still there was little amount of memory increase. Why Heap memory is not reclaiming the memory when fragments are removed from the stack. I am tracing the log from all fragments that every fragments onDestroy() is called still memory is not reclaimed. Subsequent increase in Memory is finally resulting in OutOfMemoryError saying Bitmap exceeds VM budget error and VM cannot allocation n bytes of size.

All Fragments will have 3 kinds of Background Images which are high in quality which are stored in resources. I am doing unbindDrawables in onDestroy() of each Fragment. For Bitmap images usage, I have limited the memory to 5th part of the Heap Memory. Still the OOME comes, All doors are closed for me and unable to find solution.

Below is the Sample Code which I will use for Fragment Navigations

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            if(fm!=null)
            {
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.llfirst, fragments1);//if second tab ft.replace(R.id.llsecond,fragments2);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
            }
```

Finally, One more question is that is there any limit for number of fragments to be used in Application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess bitmap size is too large. It's not getting deallocated properly and gc cannot reclaim memory. Hope this helps.

XMl layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:id="@+id/RootView"
 >

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();

unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.RootView));
System.gc();
}

private void unbindDrawables(View view) {
    if (view.getBackground() != null) {
    view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
    }
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
        unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
        }
    ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already implemented the above code. Its very much strange that after calling System.gc() also it is not reclaiming the memory

Comment: 1 suggestion. Use a MAT Analyzer and then you can track memory leaks with it. GC will not recycle the memory at once you called. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk. Have a look at this link.

Comment: bitmap.recycle() will also avoid memory leaks. Do this once the bitmap is no longer needed.

Comment: Any luck getting the solution. if you do solve please post the answer.

Comment: No solution, still the problems comes on. If I get succeeded then I definitely post the answer.